# How can I split profiles?

Tags: support, profile-page, login, network-profile

How would one potentially split the accounts that one owns in relation to the different Stack Exchange sites?

I would like to separate one of them out from my other accounts (that is to say, remove it from my profile, but not actually delete it). My profile is linked to my Gmail account, so I sign into all my accounts using SSO.

<sub>Apologies if this has been asked before.</sub>

Comment: Okay, but I don't really think that answered my question. The answer to that question (which isn't accepted) is seven years old, so I'm not sure the instructions are still relevant. I took a look at the idea of changing email address for the account I want to separate out from the others, but it says that changing the email address for that, would also change the email address for all accounts.

Comment: Stumbler, alas, this thing is not possible.

Comment: Well, it's not possible to really split profiles. The way around this which is described in the dupe is still relevant as far as I can tell.